# regex pattern doesnt match the code

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a string, which represents the maximum filesize, in a textfile. I'm using Python 3.4.3 and regex. I've tested the pattern in Pythex editor http://pythex.org/. The Pattern works but when I tested with python I get nothing, `m` returns `None`, it's like the match wasn't performed!

### Userspace_info.txt

```
Filestorage information
{
  Size in kilobyte            : 768
  Size in byte                : 786432
  Maximum filesize is         : 782336
  Used                        : No (marked as empty or invalid)
}
```

### Python code

```
import re
Userspace="Userspace_info.txt"
Form =r"\s{1,}Maximum filesize is \s{1,}:?\s*([0-9]{1,})"
p = re.compile(Form) 
m = p.match(Userspace)
print (m)
if m != None:
   A= m.group()
   print (A)
else:
print("couldnt find the Maximal userspace memory size")
```

Comment: First, read the file in, then, match what you need with the regex passing the file *contents* to the `m = p.match(Userspace_contents)`.

Comment: `p.match(Userspace)` This matches agains the _filename_, **not** the _content_ of the file!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file's content with:

```
open(Userspace).read()
```

You should pass this into your `match`:

```
m = p.match(open(Userspace).read())
```

Comment: That's a good start, but this in itself won't work, as OP is using `match`, not `search`

Answer (score 0):

`Userspace` is the *name* of the file, not the content. First, you have to `open` the file, and then match the regex against the individual lines.

```
import re
with open("Userspace_info.txt") as Userspace:
    Form =r"\s{1,}Maximum filesize is \s{1,}:?\s*([0-9]{1,})"
    p = re.compile(Form) 
    for line in Userspace:
        m = p.match(line)
        if m != None:
           A= m.group()
           print (A)
           break
    else:
        print("couldnt find the Maximal userspace memory size")
```

This uses a `for/else` loop, i.e. the final `print` line is printed only if the loop finished normally, i.e. if the `break` has not been triggered.

Comment: :Thanks a lot :)) it works perfect !! I only added 'A= m.group(1)' to match the 782336 string.